# docker desktop can't find images and containers after running wsl2 mount command

Tags: windows, docker, wsl-2, docker-desktop, ubuntu-22.04

I am using wsl2 with Ubuntu-22 and also Docker Desktop. I recently tried to fix an issue with Ubuntu-22 disk space but after running the following command my docker desktop cannot find my images and containers. I have provided the screenshots to help you get closer to my problem.

```
wsl.exe --mount <paht-to-ext4> --vhd --bare
```

1. screenshot of commands before getting the issue.

[image]

2. screenshot of docker issue.
   [image]
3. `wsl` mount points after the issue.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop Docker Desktop:

   `system try -> Righ Click -> Quit Docker Desktop`
2. run in PowerShell:

```
wsl --unmount
```

3. Start Docker Desktop again.
4. Start Distro in wsl.

```
wsl --shutdown
wsl
```